# Poco C++ Android JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, poco-libraries

I am not exactly sure if I understand it correctly, so I want to optimize the network requests a bit for my android application and used so far OkhttpClient, HttpUrlConnection, and Java Sockets but am not happy with the performance. I found a nice C++ library called Poco and thought I would give it a try so I cross compile it for the different ABIs. So far so good now the point is that I am not sure about, do I need to write my own JNI wrapper for poco so that I can use these libraries because I mean to compile it only for the different ABIs doesn’t mean I can use it right out of the box, or? And what is the best practice to do so? Do I need to add the JNI let’s call it method annotations to the .cpp files to use it? 
The Reason why i think about some native library is that i start multiple http get requests to determine the throughput so i simply start 4 http requests with a countdown latch and read the bytes from the source `response.body!!.source()`with OkHttpClient.

```
        try {
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            try {
                val downloadReader = response.body!!.source()
                awaitStart()
                val byteArr = ByteArray(8192)        
                while (!emitter.isCancelled && !downloadReader.exhausted()) {
                    val read = downloadReader.read(byteArr)
                    if (read == -1) {
                        emitter.onComplete()
                        break
                    } else {
                        emitter.onNext(read)
                }
            }
        }
```

So since i use RxJava i will start each http request in a `Schedulers.newThread()` and aggregate each emission and sample a specific time the results to do my calculation. If I observe the throughput via Android Studio Network Profiler i get too much fluctuating values see:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your application is network-bound, switching to JNI will not solve anything.

Comment: what do you mean with "network-bound"? So what i do is a simple http get request to gather a large binary file in multiple threads.

Comment: network-bound means that (unless you are doing something spectacularly wrong) the performance of fetching files is limited by the capacity of your network connection. Have you measured the throughput you get and compared it to, say, a laptop connected to the same wireless network using `curl` to fetch files?

Comment: Yes, but my main concern is that on Android i have a strange behavior that everytime i got a schema like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lykfm.png and I am not sure why i get these peaks and tails the whole time that makes it difficult for me.

Comment: Can you put that graph in the question along with some information about it? ie Is this a single HTTP connection fetching one file or several fetches in sequence? Are you multithreading HTTP fetches as well? Do you see the same on a non-Android device? What code produced this?

Comment: I edit my question hopefully it is enough info?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208398/discussion-between-edhair-and-botje).